# Having different start and end times for each day of the week in a weekly view in Angular-Calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-calendar

I am using angular-calendar library and my days for mwl-calendar-week-view have different dayStartHour and different dayEndHour.

Is it possible to have different start and end times for each day in the week view?
If yes, how?

And if not, how can I achieve this, please? The dayEndHour and dayStartHour parameters only accept a single integer, not an array of integers.

For now I have :

```
 <mwl-calendar-week-view
    *ngSwitchCase="'week'"
    [currentTimeMarkerTemplate]="currentTimeMarkerTemplate"
    [dayEndHour]="dayEndHour"
    [dayStartHour]="dayStartHour"
    [events]="events"
    [hourSegments]="hourSegments"
    [refresh]="refresh"
    [viewDate]="viewDate">
</mwl-calendar-week-view>
```

where

```
 dayStartHour: number = 8;
 dayEndHour: number = 19;
```

but I want to have `dayStartHours` and `dayEndHours` like this

```
dayStartHours: number[] = [8, 7, 9, 7, 8, 10, 9];
dayEndHours: number[] = [16, 17, 18, 16, 17, 15, 14];
```